# How to pass some data to observer data?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have a popup for login in custom page
when user login from custom page i want to trigger an event "log in"

& in that event i am trying to pass the "`location`" property.

I am not sure how can i append this location to the event
so that in my observer i can fetch it as

```
$observer->getEvent()->getData('location');
```

Any thoughts on this ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $_eventManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
) {
    $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
}

public function execute()
{
    //you can pass param value and set condition here as per your requirement. 
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'customer_login_observer',
                ['location' => $location, 'request' => $this->getRequest()]
            );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer kushal, can i extend the event for exg i am trying for "customer_login" event, can i extend the dispatch of this event in my custom file ?

Comment: No you can't extend an event but you can create multiple observers for that event in different modules. Though the order of execution is not guaranteed.